# Ignite cluster on kuberntes

Tags: kubernetes, ignite, kubernetes-pod

I have build on one kuberntes vm 2 pods of ignite - and when I check state everything looks fine but it isn't working fine on kuberntes cluster

I set discoveryIP as you can see  attached as well
can you  suggest why? and what can be done?

```
    <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <!--
                    Enables Kubernetes IP finder and setting custom namespace and service names.
                -->
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder">
                    <property name="namespace" value="production"/>
                    <property name="serviceName" value="{{ include "ignite.fullname" . }}"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

shard logs and status below.

```
> Cluster  ID: 0d910f16-fc9e-4837-b502-eecd100c530e Cluster tag:
> loving_lovelace
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Cluster is active Command [STATE] finished with code: 0 Control
> utility has completed execution at: 2020-12-17T08:20:26.317
```

however when I deploy the exact same chart on cluster I recived the following errors:

```
Failed to activate cluster.
Connection to cluster failed. Latest topology update failed.
Execution time: 33284 ms
command terminated with exit code 2
```

and in logs:

```
Dec 17, 2020 10:14:55 AM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
SEVERE: Failed to get registered addresses from IP finder on start (retrying every 2000ms; change 'reconnectDelay' to configure the frequency of retries).
class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses.
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:170)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.registeredAddresses(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1965)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.resolvedAddresses(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1913)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.sendJoinRequestMessage(ServerImpl.java:1277)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:1105)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:462)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2120)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:299)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:967)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1935)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1298)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2046)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1698)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1114)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1032)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:918)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:817)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:687)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:656)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:353)
        at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:300)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:158)
        ... 20 more

Dec 17, 2020 10:19:55 AM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
SEVERE: Failed to get registered addresses from IP finder on start (retrying every 2000ms; change 'reconnectDelay' to configure the frequency of retries).
class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses.
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:170)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.registeredAddresses(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1965)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.resolvedAddresses(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1913)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.sendJoinRequestMessage(ServerImpl.java:1277)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:1105)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:462)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2120)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:299)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:967)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1935)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1298)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2046)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1698)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1114)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1032)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:918)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:817)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:687)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:656)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:353)
        at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:300)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:158)
        ... 20 more

Dec 17, 2020 10:24:55 AM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
SEVERE: Failed to get registered addresses from IP finder on start (retrying every 2000ms; change 'reconnectDelay' to configure the frequency of retries).
class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses.
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:170)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.registeredAddresses(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1965)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.resolvedAddresses(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1913)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.sendJoinRequestMessage(ServerImpl.java:1277)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:1105)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:462)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2120)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:299)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:967)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1935)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1298)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2046)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1698)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1114)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1032)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:918)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:817)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:687)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:656)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:353)
        at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:300)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:158)
        ... 20 more

Dec 17, 2020 10:29:56 AM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
SEVERE: Failed to get registered addresses from IP finder on start (retrying every 2000ms; change 'reconnectDelay' to configure the frequency of retries).
class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses.
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:170)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.registeredAddresses(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1965)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.resolvedAddresses(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1913)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.sendJoinRequestMessage(ServerImpl.java:1277)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:1105)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:462)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2120)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:299)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:967)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1935)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1298)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2046)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1698)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1114)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1032)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:918)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:817)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:687)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:656)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:353)
        at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:300)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:158)
        ... 20 more

Dec 17, 2020 10:34:56 AM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
SEVERE: Failed to get registered addresses from IP finder on start (retrying every 2000ms; change 'reconnectDelay' to configure the frequency of retries).
class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses.
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:170)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.registeredAddresses(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1965)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.resolvedAddresses(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1913)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.sendJoinRequestMessage(ServerImpl.java:1277)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:1105)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:462)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2120)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:299)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:967)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1935)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1298)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2046)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1698)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1114)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1032)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:918)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:817)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:687)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:656)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:353)
        at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:300)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:158)
    ... 20 more
```

Service -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "ignite.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ include "ignite.fullname" . }}
spec:
  ports:
    - name: jdbc
      port: 11211
      targetPort: 11211
    - name: spi-communication
      port: 47100
      targetPort: 47100
    - name: spi-discovery
      port: 47500
      targetPort: 47500
    - name: jmx
      port: 49112
      targetPort: 49112
    - name: sql
      port: 10800
      targetPort: 10800
    - name: rest
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: thin-clients
      port: 10900
      targetPort: 10900
  selector:
    app: {{ include "ignite.fullname" . }}
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: clusterIP
```

Comment: can you edit the question and share the full stacktrace of this exception? Sometimes this could happen due to authorization issues, but it's hard to say precisely at the moment.

Comment: You might also refer to the https://www.gridgain.com/docs/web-console/latest/deploying-amazon-eks for examples

Comment: thanks, I edited more from the logs the error  messages are repeating

Answer (score 1):

Well, from the error, it seems that the default K8s service is not working or probably doesn't exist:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Please, check the following documentation: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/kubernetes-ip-finder. By default Kubernetes IP Finder tries to reach the "/kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local:443" that might not be true in your case. I think you need to check your URL and adjust the parameter:

> setMasterUrl(String)  Sets the host name of the Kubernetes API server.    https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local:443

Could you also add some notes about your deployment or k8s version to the question?

Comment: im kind of new to k8s what do you mena in default K8s service?
for me eerthing seems as it should be in docs I added to post service file

Comment: I see is using this server which is ip is the same for each vnm in kiberiq cluster, could this work only on single node?
$ kubectl get svc -n default
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.233.0.1   <none>        443/TCP   43h